# Load View if load data complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I change the view programmatically like that:

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"edit"];
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem is, that when I change the view, that the data are not completely loaded. How can I say, that it should wait, until the data is loaded?

Comment: how do you load the data in the view?

Comment: Yes, like Mahoud said, what data are you talking about? If you simply want to set the new viewcontroller's properties you can do that between the time where you instantiated it and when you presented it, just the same way you did with setting the new viewcontroller's modalPresentationStyle property. Is there other "data" that also needs to be set up in the new viewcontroller before it's ready for use?

Comment: Sorry, I was maybe not clear. Even I click a button, it should open a new ViewController with a new class. In the new class (its a tableviewclass) I do load data from an external database in to the table view. Now i wanna wait, until the data be downloaded successfully and after that, changing the view.

Comment: Show us the code for loading data from external database. Is it blocked based or delegate based ? How you figure out that data was loaded ?